# Datatable Select Function

Tags: c#, datatable

Trying to select fields where 'Expected Closure Date' is less than todays date, and deleting them from the table.  However getting error like Missing operand after 'closure' operator.

```
DateTime Tdy=DateTime.Now;
 var rows = dt.Select("Expected closure date < "+Tdy+"");
 foreach (var row in rows)
         row.Delete();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need , Tested

```
var rows = dt.Select(string.Format("[Expected closure date] < '{0}'", Tdy));
```

---

Here is full working sample

```
using System;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
  class Program
  {    

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      string col = "Expected closure date";
      dt.Columns.Add(col,typeof(DateTime));

      dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) );

      Console.WriteLine("Total rows in dt " + dt.Rows.Count);

      DateTime Tdy = DateTime.Now;
      var rows = dt.Select(string.Format("[Expected closure date] <= '{0}'", Tdy));
      foreach (var row in rows)
        row.Delete();
      Console.WriteLine("Total rows in dt " + dt.Rows.Count);

      Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is output

```
Total rows in dt 1
Total rows in dt 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime Tdy=DateTime.Now;
 var rows = dt.Select("myDateTimecolumn<'"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"'");
 foreach (var row in rows)
         row.Delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the date in octothorpes:

```
dt.Select("myDateTimecolumn < #" + tdy.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "#");
```